# How to query mongo db with a nested model?

Tags: json, database, mongodb, aggregate

I have data similar to the below in my mongodb table called Resources.

```
{  
   "_id":"testuser",
   "_class":"com.Resources",
   "allocations":[  
      {  
         "contractId":"5083",
         "status":"UNKNOWN"
      }
   ]
}
{  
   "_id":"testuser",
   "_class":"com.Resources",
   "allocations":[  
      {  
         "contractId":"5084",
         "status":"Dead"
      }
   ]
}
{  
   "_id":"testuser2",
   "_class":"com.Resources",
   "allocations":[  
      {  
         "contractId":"5085",
         "status":"Live"
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to run a query in a shell that returns all contractIDs and its status for each _id, which is my resourceID effectively in the table. The format should be "_id - contractId - status". For example when run with the above data, we should see the below:

```
testuser - 5083 - UNKNOWN
testuser - 5084 - Dead
testuser2 - 5085 - Live
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
db.getCollection('Collection').find(/*Some Query*/).forEach(function(data){
    data.allocations.forEach(function(result){
        print(data._id + '-' + result.contractId + '-' + result.status); 
    })
})
```

Comment: For some reason the command ends with a TypeError saying the find(...).forEach(...) is undefined. Not sure if this means there is no more data to retrieve or it is stopping mid-query with an error

Comment: which mongo version you are using?

Comment: I am using version 3.4.0. I am also adding a .toArray() to the end of the query so I can get the entire dump in my shell to copy all to clipboard for post processing.

Comment: It also works in 3.4.0, but the executions ends with the TypeError as mentioned above. I dont beleive I am missing any data, but thinking why does it error out at the end.